# Pax Exam Karaf: mavenBundle configuration option works, bundle with file: URL doesn't

Tags: apache-karaf, pax-exam

This works with Pax Exam native container (Pax Exam 2.3.1), but not with Pax Exam Karaf container (0.5.2) for me:

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {
    return options(
            // karafDistributionConfiguration()
            // .frameworkUrl(
            // maven().groupId("org.apache.karaf")
            // .artifactId("apache-karaf").type("zip"))
            // .karafVersion("2.2.6").name("Apache Karaf"),
            provision(bundle("reference:file:/path/to.jar")));
}
```

A test checking that the bundle is installed:

```
@Inject
BundleContext bundleContext = null;

@Test
public void sameRepositoryProvidesFBServiceAndUserService() {
    for (Bundle b : bundleContext.getBundles()) {
        if (b.getSymbolicName().equals(myBundleName)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    fail("Bundle " + myBundleName + " not found");
}
```

If I uncomment `karafDistributionConfiguration` and  replace `bundle(url)` with `mavenBundle(groupId, artifactId)`, test passes again under Pax Exam Karaf. Is it possible to fi it? I need to use `bundle` to run tests against development versions of bundles in my workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a timing issue, fixed in 0.5.3.